# pandas bar plot not displaying what I need

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas DataFrame:

```
   data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
                 'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
                 'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 1.4, 2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to get something like this inside a Python notebook:
[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

q = p.set_index(['state'])
q['pop'].plot(kind='bar')
```

which gives this:
[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Where is `year` coming into play here? I thought that's supposed to be your x axis.

Comment: `year` should probably appear somewhere in my python code but I don't know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.pivot(index='year', columns='state', values='pop').plot(kind='bar')
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots) show that the columns of the `DataFrame` appear as the categories in the plot.  [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) reshapes your data by pivoting the unique items in the "state" column as individual columns.

Comment: In your example you want to plot the states side by side as separate categories.  The docs show that the different columns appear as the categories.  Pivoting your DataFrame turns the states into the column index, so the call to `pivot` is just reshaping the data into the format the it needs to be for the kind of plot you want.

Comment: For df's with no legend, one value per year(no states), it can be df.pivot.set_index("year").plot.bar()plot(kind='bar'). I used it for barplotting of SKLearn feature selection which is featureScores.nlargest(5,'Score').